# How to avoid extra or unnecessary renders of a child component when switching views?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

If I have two parent components that render conditionally based on a flag, and if both parent components share a a child component, that really never changes, how can I avoid re-rendering that child component?

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/prod-cloud-lo89h?file=/src/MainComponent.js).

As you can see, I even tried to use `React.memo`, but `rendered side` prints regardless.

Comment: It will re-render every time because you passed it as a component property. You need to exclude your Side component from children and use it separately inside parent.

Comment: Didn't you get the answer?  If you did, then accept the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The child component, `<Side />`, is rendering every time because: you're rendering this child component as a child component of either `<SecondaryTemplate />` or `<PrimaryTemplate />`. While you programmatically (switching view) render anyone of this, other immediately gets unmounted completely from the DOM, as `<Side />` is a child of the component just got unmounted, it no longer exists in the DOM, and when another one renders, it renders its child component because React algorithm run on virtual DOM knows in no way about the  that exists before, hence it has no meaning to expect that it will reder only once whether it changes or not.

To understand this you can look at this:
https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-khayyam-14ls0?file=/src/MainComponent.js

Where I forked your code, look at the console, you will see that when you switch the view one component gets unmounted (and hence its child `<Side />` too).